# Unable to launch Microsoft Edge browser using UFT

Tags: microsoft-edge, hp-uft, uft14

I am using Windows 10, UFT version is 12.54, and my Edge browser is 90.0.818.66 (64 bit). I followed the steps in the link below

https://eyeontesting.com/answers/microsoft-edge-browser-and-uft-1254/#gsc.tab=0

And I used, `SystemUtil.Run  "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe", "<my test url>"` to launch the browser and get the URL, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

That version is already the MS edge based on Chromium. The Link you mention refers to the old Microsoft Only Edge version.

[Here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Work_with_CEF_Applications.htm?Highlight=webdriver) is the Full Description from Microfocus, although I'm not sure if your UFT version will support it. (WebUtil Object is needed)

Simplified this is what you have to do (in your scripts):

1. Start your Browser with the Webdriver Enabled (special Command Line Parameters when starting the Browser) -- remember the Port where Webdriver requests will be accepted
2. Instruct UFT to attach to the Browser Using the WebUtil.AttachRemoteDebugging - use the Port from Above. You can even define the Webdriver to be used

Caveats:

1. You will be able to do Replay but no Recording
2. Works on any Browser or App that support the Webdriver Protocol
3. Reusing Existing Browser Sessions is very cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 2 commands, both should work:

SystemUtil.Run "msedge.exe"

WebUtil.LaunchBrowser "Edge"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).